# Skyrim Sound files Missing

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got Skyrim bought off of the internet, but it's missing the sound files, or maybe they're just corrupted.Either way none of the voices or sounds work but I can see the chat animations.

Anyone know where I might find them?

Comment: Make sure you check your default sound device too. Mine defaulted to my Turtle Beach headset and not my speakers. Took me a few minutes to figure that out.

Comment: Where did you buy Skyrim from? Was it a legitimate retailer or a scammy site? Is it a digital download? The physical media? Does the physical media *look* authentic?

Comment: if its from steam, try verifying the integrity of your files: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335

Answer (score 1):

Some people have sound problems unless you change your selected audio device to the basic setting: 16bit 44.1KHz. The game sometimes crashes due to 24bit audio. More likely one of the other comments about the wrong audio device being selected is the problem.